# Custom jQuery UI download with only datepicker doesn't include all css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm puzzled by what might be a really simple thing to do or understand.

So I downloaded jQuery UI package with the themeroller with [these](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.4&components=1000000000001000000000000000000000&zThemeParams=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) settings. I only chose datepicker and a custom theme. But when I try to use it the calendar doesn't look right:

[image]

I'v added these to my test page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='Scripts/jqueryui/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js") %>'></script>
```

After investigating more, I realized that the custom css file that was created for me doesn't include the class .ui-datepicker.

So the question is, is this by design? Do I need to add still another base jquery ui css-file? I did not see any mention of this if that is the case. And why is that not included in my package if I need to do that? Or is this a bug? What should I do to get a package that only includes the css/js I need for only datepicker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this [Google Code source](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/branches/labs/datepicker2/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?r=3875)

EDIT:
got it. Simply u need to select the Widget tick like [this page](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.4&components=1100000000001000000000000000000000&zThemeParams=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)

Comment: It still does not solve the problem, it's still missing alot of the classes needed, like .ui-icon for example.

Comment: There is no my code, download the package from the link in my post and open the index.html, you can see it's broken.

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem. But I still think it's a bug in the downloader since it does not select "Widget" when one selects datepicker.